# Glossaries with section as counter does not work in appendix

Tags: sectioning, numbering, glossaries, appendices

I would like to use the glossaries package with the option `counter=section`.
This works well as long as I don't use any glossary entries in the appendix.
It seems the section counter is reset by the `\appendix` command.
It turns out that section A.1 is called 1.1, B.1 is called 2.1 and so on.

I am using the makeglossaries script and a minimal example is:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[counter=section]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{gte}{name=GTE,description={Glossary Test Entry}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Normal chapter}

\section{Normal section}

This is section 1.1 without a glossary entry.

\chapter{Normal chapter}

\section{Normal section}

A \gls{gte} in section 2.1.

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix chapter}

\section{Appendix section}

A \gls{gte} in appendix A.1.

\printglossary

The glossary indicates appearance in 1.1 and 2.1 instead of 2.1 and A.1.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: It's a bug. I'll get it fixed.

Comment: Does anyone knows a quick and dirty fix? I have to finalyse my thesis and would prefere having a working glossary.

Comment: @JanHajer I've fixed the bug and uploaded v3.05 to CTAN. It may take a day or two for it to propagate through the mirrors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works well. The only question remaining is, if the abstract really is chapter 0.0 or if one can avoid having 0.0 appearing in the numberlist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade to `glossaries` version 3.05 (once it's worked its way through the CTAN mirrors).